# Grab most recently played iTunes song using Java

Tags: java, com, itunes

What is the easiest way to get the information about the last song played in iTunes into a Java program?  I have looked at JACOB and iTunes COM but they seem like overkill.  If that's the only way to go, could anyone provide a good example next to the first google result?  A 'hack' method is acceptable as well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is pretty callable from AppleScript, I'd start there.

Looks like Apple's stuff is deprecated, [jasconn](https://jasconn.dev.java.net/) looks like it's the way forward.

EDIT - Point taken about the mention of COM, points the finger at Windows rather than a Mac.  My suggestion for the super hack approach would be to fire up [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and see what iTunes writes out and to where when you play a song.

Comment: He mentions COM, so Applescript may not be an option.

Comment: He only looked at COM, so Applescript may still be an option

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows you must use COM to talk to iTunes.

There is an iTunes SDK available which provides glue you can use.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could use lastfm web service. it will have all recently played songs in a xml feed.

u just need to be connected to the internet when u play a song